# Albums disappears from gallery

Tags: photos

Some time back I was asked by the PHOTOS app to move photos to my account. When I confirmed the same I have found to my dismay that they have been removed from my albums in gallery. Now how do I retrieve those photos back to my albums

Comment: Please provide more info. Which phone? Android version? Which photos/gallery app?

Comment: Sign into the google account that they were synced under initially when they were on the phone, or go to photos.google.com and sign in there to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the photos are on your google account by going to https://photos.google.com. (sign in if needed) then verify they are there.

If they are then:

Go to accounts and sync.
add account.
allow 5 minutes to sync in background.
open accounts and sync and sync now by hitting menu or 3 lines/dots and hitting sync.
Update/install google photos app and then open it.
change account under the google photos app to correct account if needed.
See if photos are there, if not, after checking wait 3 minutes and check again.

Another option is too use the website to download all the photos to your sdcard by clicking on the "photos" section and then hitting the 3 dot menu in top right and hit "select photos", select the ones you want, then 3 dot menu again and hit download photos.